# Dimension of the center of a subalgebra of a simple algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, central-simple-algebras

Let $F$ be a field. Let $A$ be a simple (associative unital) $F$-algebra with center reduced to $F$. Let $B$ be a $F$-subalgebra of $A$;
assume that $A$ is can be generated as left $B$-module by $n$ elements.

Does it follow that $\dim_F(Z(B))\le n$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $[Z(B):F]$ here?

Comment: $Z(B)$ is centralizer of $B$ in $A$.and $[Z(B):A]$ is index of $Z(B)$ in $F$

Comment: $F$ is a submodule of $Z(B)$.

Comment: yes exactly.I mean that

Comment: So $[Z(B):F]$ is the cardinal of $Z(B)/F$? what is $F$? If $F$ is an infinite field, then this index is either 1 or $\infty$. If you mean something else (e.g., you mean the codimension assuming $F$ is a field), please edit to make your question understandable.

Comment: As currently stated, it seems that the answer is no for $A=B$.